# Is there anyway to configure Google account for Windows 8 Sync?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, sync, google-workspace

Recently upgraded to Windows 8. The problem is a lot of Sync features requires Microsoft account to linked. Even though I have one, I don't want to spare one for Sync purpose. Additionally, Google-Chrome's sync feature is absolutely charming.  So I prefer Google for storing my data.

So,
1) Is there anyway to replace Microsoft Sync with other accounts by patching or modifying any byte?
2) I want to replace Maps, Weather, and all possible apps with Google. I've see Mail can be done. What are the all other possible Metro apps?

Comment: No, the mail account is pretty much it, everything else would require an application written by Google.

Comment: I do not see any effort you would gain in changing the account used for syncing.

Comment: How can't I? If I'm using my office pc, perhaps, I might integrate my home pc options there, through my Google account.

Comment: Yes, but what is the advantage of using the Google account instead of the Microsoft account, assumed they both would provide same functionality?

Comment: I dont see how you cant just simply put a shortcut from IE of all the appropriate pages on your metro and get this working. Place Gmail and Gdrive and upload your stuff from your chrome OS to Gdrive and access like this on Windows 8...

Answer (score 1):

**1. Replacing Sync**

The Microsoft Live account is not just used for authentication, like eg. on many websites like this website here, but also for storing very specific operating system settings. Google's account infrastructure is very sure not aware about these settings, so only the Microsoft Live account can be used for that.

**2. Changing Apps**

"Metro" apps can only be installed from the official Microsoft Store, so if the desired app is not in the Store, you cannot install it. But I'm pretty sure, it's just a mater of time util Google publishes those applications, you have asked for.

Comment: Thanks for info. Since I didn't used Chrome OS, I thought may be there is such an option which can be used for Windows too. So an app developer can't set/test his metro app on his own machine?

Comment: A developer can run his own application, but he has to request a special, very time limited developer license for this purpose. This allows him to launch the apps he is developing during the time of development.

Comment: Another thing to point is that this request for dev license is free provided you have visual studio installed.

Comment: See [Install a Windows 8 Modern UI app without the Windows Store](http://superuser.com/a/499581/138343).